# Is there a way in python write json on redis record by record

Tags: python, json, redis

I have the following json file content :

```py
{
    "transactions":
       "tr1": {
            "type":"deposit",
            "account_id":123456789012345,
            "amount":20000.0
        },
       "tr2": {
            "type":"deposit",
            "account_id":555456789012345,
            "amount":20000.0
        },
    "tr3":{
            "type":"payment",
            "account_id":123456789012345,
            "amount":20000.0
        },
    "tr4":{
            "type":"transfer",
            "from":555456789012345,
            "to":123456789012345,
            "amount":20000.0
        }
}
```

I need to write the information of each transaction on Redis using python program! is there a way to do this ?

I have tryied this , but it insert everything under one key 'traninfo'

```py
data=json.load(f)
for i in data['transactions']:
    r.execute_command('JSON.SET','traninfo','.', json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: This particular code snippet does not contain valid JSON, but yes, python is perfectly capable of reading JSON and writing to redis.

Comment: @jojo Welcome to stackoverflow. What did you already try? Do you have a piece of code   You should read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question.

Comment: I reformated the code snippet acctually .. and what I need to know is how !

Comment: Did you mean to use a different string than `'traninfo'` in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Notice from redis-py 4.0 you can use a "safer" API:
    r.json().set('traninfo','$', json.dumps(data))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matter with the snippet you give is that at each loop you put the whole json as value of your key. As the key is the same, you write four times the same value in your redis.

From your JSON, I guess you want to have one key per transaction in your redis: `"tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr4"`. If you do:

```py
for i in data['transactions']:
    print(i)
```

it will print:

```
"tr1"
"tr2"
"tr3"
"tr4"
```

you can modify your existing code like this:

```py
data=json.load(f)
for i in data['transactions']:
    r.execute_command('JSON.SET', i,'.', json.dumps(data['transactions'][i]))
```

it will do what you want. But, there is a better way, the `items` function that allows you to iterates on key and values at the same time:

```py
data=json.load(f)
for key, value in data['transactions'].items():
    r.execute_command('JSON.SET', key, '.', json.dumps(value))
```

I let you use the @Guy Korland improvement about redis api.

Comment: Thank you very much! the two methods that you suggests work effectively with my case. thanks again for your clear and direct solution.